PrimeNG Table Coumn filtering working - Documentation not clear or may be outdated
My aim is to display a list of individuals to in a table component and filter and or search based on certain criteria. My template code is as follows:
<div class="flex flex-col bg-gray-100 p-6 mx-auto w-auto">
  <header class="bg-white shadow p-4 flex items-center justify-between">
    <h1 class="text-lg font-bold">East Portland Constituency Voters </h1>
    <div>
      <button class="bg-blue-600 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">Logout</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <br>

  <div class="mt-8 bg-white p-6 rounded shadow mb-4">

    <div class="card">
      <p-table #dt
        [value]="voters"
        dataKey="id"
        [rows]="10"
        [globalFilterFields]="['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'affiliation', 'role', 'gender']"
        [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50]"
        [paginator]="true"
        [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '75rem' }">
        <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
          <div class="flex justify-between">
            <p-button label="Clear" [outlined]="true" icon="pi pi-filter-slash" (onClick)="clear(dt)" />
            <span class="p-input-icon-left ml-autod">
              <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
              <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue"
                (input)="dt.filterGlobal(getEventValue($event), 'contains')"  placeholder="Search for voter" />
            </span>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
          <tr>
            <th style="min-width:10rem">
              <div class="flex align-items-center">
                First Name
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="min-width:10rem">
              <div class="flex align-items-center">
                Last Name
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="min-width:15rem">
              <div class="flex align-items-center">
                Email
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="min-width:15rem">
              <div class="flex align-items-center">
                Affiliation
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="min-width:15rem">
              <div class="flex align-items-center">
                Role
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="min-width:15rem">
              <div class="flex align-items-center">
                Gender
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th style="min-width:15rem">
              <div class="flex align-items-center">
                <p-columnFilter field="affiliation" matchMode="in" [showMenu]="false">
                  <ng-template pTemplate="filter"  let-filter="filterCallback" >
                    <p-multiSelect [(ngModel)]="selectedAffils" [options]="affiliations"  placeholder="Any"
                      (onChange)="filter($event.value)">
                    </p-multiSelect>
                  </ng-template>
                </p-columnFilter>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="min-width:15rem">
              <div class="flex align-items-center">
                <p-columnFilter field="role" matchMode="in" [showMenu]="false">
                  <ng-template pTemplate="filter"   let-filter="filterCallback">
                    <p-multiSelect [(ngModel)]="selectedRoles" [options]="roles"   placeholder="Any"
                      (onChange)="filter($event.value)" >
                    </p-multiSelect>
                  </ng-template>
                </p-columnFilter>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="min-width:10rem">
              <div class="flex align-items-center">
                <p-columnFilter field="gender" matchMode="in" [showMenu]="false">
                  <ng-template pTemplate="filter"   let-filter="filterCallback">
                    <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selectedGender"  [options]="genders" placeholder="Any"
                      (onChange)="filter($event.value)" >
                    </p-dropdown>
                  </ng-template>
                </p-columnFilter>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-voter>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{ voter.firstName }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ voter.lastName }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ voter.email }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ voter.voterAffiliation }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ voter.supporterRole }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ voter.gender }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6">No voters found.</td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
      </p-table>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

Component Code:
import { VoterServiceService } from './../services/voter-service.service';
import { Component, inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SUPPORT_ROLE, Voter, VOTER_AFFILIATION } from '../data/data.schema';
import { Table, TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import { MultiSelect, MultiSelectChangeEvent } from 'primeng/multiselect';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-voters',
  standalone: true,
  imports:[TableModule, MultiSelect,CommonModule,FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './search-voters.component.html',
  styleUrl: './search-voters.component.css'
})
export class SearchVotersComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedAffils: string[]
  selectedRoles: string[]
  selectedGender: string;
  voter: Voter | undefined;
  layout: string = 'list'
  voters!: Voter[] | undefined;
  genders: string[] | undefined;
  roles: string[] | undefined;
  affiliations: string[] | undefined;
  private voterServiceService = inject(VoterServiceService);
  searchValue:string | undefined;
  loading:boolean;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.voters = this.voterServiceService.getVoters();

    this.genders = [
      'Male' ,
      'Female',
    ];
    this.roles = [
       SUPPORT_ROLE.CLUSTER_SUPERVISOR ,
       SUPPORT_ROLE.PD_CAPTAIN ,
       SUPPORT_ROLE.INDOOR_AGENT ,
       SUPPORT_ROLE.OUTDOOR_AGENT ,
       SUPPORT_ROLE.COUNCILLOR ,
       SUPPORT_ROLE.MINISTER_OF_PARLIAMENT ,
       SUPPORT_ROLE.RUNNER ,
       SUPPORT_ROLE.DRIVER ,
    ];
    this.affiliations = [
       VOTER_AFFILIATION.JLP,
       VOTER_AFFILIATION.PNP,
       VOTER_AFFILIATION.NK,
       VOTER_AFFILIATION.DEAD,
    ];

  }


  viewSelect(select : MultiSelectChangeEvent){
    console.log(select)
  }


  clear(table:Table){
     table.clear();
     this.selectedAffils = []
     this.selectedGender = ''
     this.selectedRoles = []
  }
  getEventValue(e: Event ){
    return (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value
  }

}


contents are being rendered but the input search functionality is working as it should. My issue is with the column filtering using the Multiselect and dropdown. Previously I tried implementing this following the documentation's approach:
    <p-columnFilter field="status" matchMode="equals" [showMenu]="false">
                  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
                      <p-dropdown
                          [(ngModel)]="value"
                          [options]="statuses"
                          (onChange)="filter($event.value)"
                          placeholder="Select One"
                          [showClear]="true">

                      </p-dropdown>
                  </ng-template>
              </p-columnFilter>   

Utilizing the value on the ngmodel directive gave resulting in a Cannot use a non-signal variable 'value' in a two-way binding expression. Template variables are read-only.ngtsc(-99) error within the code. Not sure what could be the issue. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

You are not using PrimeFaces

I am using PrimeNG as per the docs. Other opponents from the library work fairly well

Try changing the [(ngModel)]='value' to a one-way class binding, [ngModel]='value'.
This is read-only, and should fix your problem.

The error goes away but the search functionality still doesn't. I find it out that the documentation outlines it using two way binding yet it's not working whenever i try

Figured it out the issue was  had to do with the typescript configuration    "strictTemplates": true this should be set to true. To use it with strictTemplates active, ngmodel should be a one way class binding and adding
appendTo="body" optionLabel="value" optionValue="value" to the select components work as well
